# MongoDb Uniqueness without Index

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to enforce uniqueness in mongodb on a non-index field? The SQL equivalent would be

```
    CREATE TABLE short_to_long_map (
    ID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    short_url varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    long_url varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
// Will succeed
    INSERT INTO short_to_long_map VALUES (1, 'https://my.url/1234', 'https://long-long-long-url.com');

// Will fail b/c same short URL
    INSERT INTO short_to_long_map VALUES (2, 'https://my.url/1234', 'https://another-long-long-long-url.com')
```

It seems like [it might](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/unique-constraints-on-arbitrary-fields/), but not sure if a proxy collection is the only way.

Comment: What is your problem to create an index?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure if an index would impact read/write performance differently than a unique non-index

Comment: It should not make any difference whether you have an unique or non-unique index. However, having no index at all will drastically reduce read and write performance.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `upsert` with `$setOnInsert`:
For example:

```
db.collection.update(
{b: "https://my.url/1234"},
{$setOnInsert: {a: 2, c: "https://another-long-long-long-url.com"}},
{upsert: true})
```

This query will create a document with fields `a`, `b`, `c` only if there is no document with this value at field `b`.

You can see it on [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_HVG1CnjEm1).

Running this query when there is a document with the same `b` value, will return:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

If there is no document with the same value at `b`, it will be created:

[can be seen here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4hRtGUhCQo8)

Comment: This solution will not overwrite the existing document. Check out the playground example.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a unique constraint without an index, an index will be created automatically. See output for your example:

```
CREATE TABLE SHORT_TO_LONG_MAP (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    short_url VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    long_url VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL
);

Table created.
    
SELECT table_name, index_type, index_name, uniqueness, GENERATED
FROM user_indexes 
WHERE table_name = 'SHORT_TO_LONG_MAP';

+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|TABLE_NAME        |INDEX_TYPE|INDEX_NAME    |UNIQUENESS|GENERATED|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|SHORT_TO_LONG_MAP |NORMAL    |SYS_C00165589 |UNIQUE    |Y        |
|SHORT_TO_LONG_MAP |NORMAL    |SYS_C00165590 |UNIQUE    |Y        |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```